# Magento: set visibility of product attribute on frontend per shop

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I would like to be able to set the visibility of a product attribute for the frontend per shop. Say we have attribute "size", I would like to show this on the product details page of shop A, but not on shop B.

In the admin catalog > attributes > manage attributes, I can set "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" to yes or no. Currently it's "no". This setting applies to all shops. I would like to set this to "yes" for one shop (or template) only.

How can I get this working?

Comment: if you seen my answer give some response

Comment: my ans is useful for not? give some response otherwise my efforts will go to in vain

Answer (score 0):

you set attribute property as per shop

here i am giving your link to set attribute visibility per shop

Please refer detail [Document LINK](http://www.human-element.com/Blog/ArticleDetailsPage/tabid/91/ArticleID/68/Magento-Attributes-Using-Different-Filterable-Attributes-Per-Category.aspx)

And let me know if you need more help from my side.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get current store information in frontend using below code

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
```

OR

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
```

OR

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

OR

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
```

After getting the current store info you can manually create any condition to show your particular attribute.
Example: Suppose I have created an attribute named as "type" and it is showing on product details page 'additional information' section of both of my store . I have created a condition to show this particular attribute only one store of my site for this i have modified template/catalog/product/view/additional.phtml page and added below code

```
 <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): 
        $store_name = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();       
         if ( ($_data['code'] != "type") || ($store_name != "english_store_view_website_2")) {  ?>
         <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }
          endforeach; ?>
```